# New to C# socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets, client

I am new to socket programming with C#. I am developing a client-server application with multiple clients. I am not quite sure how to form a communication between the server and its clients.

- Is it a good idea for the clients to send keyword messages (i.e. 'string') that will invoke the server to do something?
- Is it a good idea for the clients to send instances of certain classes (that I created) which need to be processed?
- Is it a good idea to send/receive files (I am using XML) between the server and the clients?

I am sorry if my questions are naive as this is my first experience developing an application with a client-server architecture.

I found [this link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-socket.htm) which has an example of such an application but I was wondering if anyone knew  any other websites/books/tutorials with explanations.

Comment: +1 to WCF recomendation. csharp-multi-threaded-socket.htm show the worse way to handle multiple connections. Creating new thread for each new client is guarantee a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a modern c# application you seldom need to resort to plain sockets to create a client-server application. Instead you can create a WCF service. (Pick a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service) and try).

Using a WCF service instead of plain sockets will save you from a lot of plumbing work with creating a protocol, parsing and that kind of stuff.